# Installing py3exiv2 on Windows with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, exif, iptc, exiv2

I tried some exif/iptc/xmp libraries for Python3, but they are all neither mature nor fully-fledged.

- exifread can only read exif information
- iptcinfo3 is not properly ported to Python3

Therefore, i tried to use **py3exiv2** on Windows 7/10.

However, i neither found a **windows wheel** for py3exiv2 nor does `pip install py3exiv2` runs out of the box on windows. There seems to be C++ bindings, that have to be compiled during pip installation.

I installed `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 standalone: Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017` 
but `pip install py3exiv2` still fails with a missing `exiv2/image.hpp` file. 
I assume, there are more dependencies missing... but i have no clue how to add this to the pip installation or fix this manually.

So i would like to ask, if you can give me some hints how to setup and install py3exiv2 properly on windows?